# JMS Call to a member function has() on null

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

Bundle version 1.3.1
| Symfony version 3.3
| PHP version 7.1.9

#### Expected behavior

After installing the different bundles (JMSTranslationBundle, JMSDIExtraBundle, checking if i had sensio/framework-extra-bundle), and after i made the right configuration in config.yml and routing_dev.yml, the right behavior should be that the /_trans lead me to a translation interface (working), and change nothing else.

#### Actual behavior

Getting on a route different from /_trans return `Call to a member function has() on null` with error 500. Therefore, the whole site is dead, except the translation UI.

#### Steps to reproduce

Install JMSTranslationBundle, then when asked, install JMSDIExtraBundle to get the web ui
After that, test the /_trans. This should work. But when you get to your others routes, they return 500 error

Comment: >Getting on a route different from /_trans return Call to a member function has() on null with error 500. ---> This is not a trace of the problem. 
If you really want help, then put some lines with the complete trace error that you get on app_dev.php

Comment: Yeah my bad ... I uninstalled them, and can't find it in logs, will try to reproduce on a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue (Sf 3.3.9/PHP 7.1.9). I have to remove the line related to "JMSDiExtraBundle" in AppKernel to make my app works again. This is the only workaround I found, not very efficient.

Very low trace log information, this is what I have:

Stack Trace:
[image]

Logs:

```
CRITICAL 19:56:59 php   Call to a member function has() on null
CRITICAL 19:56:59 request   Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Call to a member function has() on null" at /Users/stephanfo/PhpstormProjects/openbuy/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php line 233
```

Exception:
[image]

Any help would be helpful.
Thanks,
Stef.

Comment: Thanks for posting the trace, i really had no time to reproduce the bug since i posted this. The issue was the same for me, and the stack_trace isn't really helpfull. I also posted the same content on their github repo since then. https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/issues/458

Comment: I "fixed" this issue by downgrading jms/di-extra-bundle to 1.7.0 . Now routing and translation WebUI works.

Comment: Ok thanks @joshas ! Will do if this is not solved at the moment i push it to prod :)

Comment: Thanks Josh. I appreciate the feedback.